# Set-ItemProperty dependency on Powershell version

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I am using Set-ItemProperty to **set a registry key** in a new PS script that I am writing. 
Since the script can run on different PS versions, I am wondering if the cmdlet could have problems with any specific PS version.

So my question is, does the cmdlet Set-ItemProperty has any dependency on the PS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmdlet exists since PowerShell v1 and as far as I know its semantics didn't change since then.

If you use features that are only available in later versions, you can use a `#requires` comment at the start of your script, e.g.:

```
#Requires -Version 3.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I went to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849844.aspx, it showed only versions 3 and 4 (in the 'Show Other Versions' dropdown). That made me ask this question!

Comment: Technet seems to only have documentation for PowerShell v3 and v4 in general there. But accessing registry keys via Get/SetItemProperty was possible in v1 already, so I think you're good.